# Server side Jquery datatable showing requested unknown parameter in laravel (FIxed) but ssearching is not working by address name

Tags: jquery, sql, laravel, join, serverside-datatable

Previous Issue has been solved but currently search is not working when I am trying to search by address name.

For your reference, I'm using "https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side" this jquery datatable.
There is a one to many relationship between a company and address (e.g. One company has many addresses).

**Migration: Companies**

```
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Migration: Addresses**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Model: Company**

```
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

**Model: Address**

```
public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
```

**CompanyController**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax()){
            $columns = array(
                0 => 'id',
                1 => 'name',
                2 => 'addresses',
                3 => 'action'
            );

            $totalData = Company::count();

            $limit = $request->input('length');
            $start = $request->input('start');
            $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
            $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

            if(empty($request->input('search.value'))){
                $companies = Company::offset($start)
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                    ->get();
                $totalFiltered = Company::count();
            }else{
                $search = $request->input('search.value');
                $companies = Company::where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                    ->whereHas('addresses',function ($q) use ($search){
                        $q->orWhere('addresses.name','like',"%{$search}%");
                    })
                    ->offset($start)
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                    ->get();
                $totalFiltered = Company::where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                    ->whereHas('addresses',function ($q) use ($search){
                        $q->orWhere('addresses.name','like',"%{$search}%");
                    })
                    ->count();
            }


            $data = array();
            $serialNo = $request->input('start');

            if($companies){
                foreach($companies as $key => $company){
                    $edit = route('companies.edit', $company->id);

                    $serialNo++;

                    $nestedData['serial'] = $serialNo;
                    $nestedData['name'] = $company->name;

                    $addresses = Address::select("*")->where('company_id',$company->id)->get();

                    $nestedData['addresses'] = array();
                    foreach ($addresses as $address){
                        array_push($nestedData['addresses'],$address->name);
                    }

                    $nestedData['action'] = "
                    <a href='{$edit}' title='Edit' class='btn btn-warning edit'><span class='fa fa-user-edit' style='color: whitesmoke'></span></a>
                    <button class='btn btn-danger' data-userid={$company->id} data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></button>
                ";
                    $data[] = $nestedData;
                }
            }

            $json_data = array(
                "draw"          => intval($request->input('draw')),
                "recordsTotal"  => intval($totalData),
                "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
                "data"          => $data
            );

            return response($json_data);

        }
```

**Ajax Script in the company index**

```
<script>
        $('#ajaxDatatable').DataTable({
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": "<span>Please wait...</span>"
            },
            "paging": true,
            "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50],
                [10, 25, 50]
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "{{route('companies.index')}}",
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "GET",
                "data": {"_token": "{{csrf_token()}}"}
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "serial"},
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "addresses"},
                {
                    "data": "action",
                    "searchable": false,
                    "orderable": false
                }
            ],
            "scrollY": 650,
            "scrollCollapse": true
        });
    </script>
```

**JSON Response getting currently when searching by address name : **

```
{"draw":4,"recordsTotal":4,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[]}
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `$json_data` please?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I've updated my post with the response.

Comment: As you can see from the `$json_data` response you've just provided, the first object item in the `"data"` array has **no** `addresses` property yet others have it.

Comment: I've found the issue and solved but now I can not search by address name.

Comment: I can't paste the current code in the comment section. let me update the codes.

Comment: Please don't update the old question since you're now asking a completely different question related to failing to search by address name. I would suggest you create a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply using [`laravel-datatable-ssp`](https://info.souldoit.com/projects/laravel-datatable-ssp) package.

.

1. Install via composer

```
composer require syamsoul/laravel-datatable-ssp
```

.

2. In your Controller, just inject `SoulDoit\DataTable\SSP` service

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use SoulDoit\DataTable\SSP;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    private $ssp;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $ssp = new SSP();

        $ssp->enableSearch();
        $ssp->allowExportAllItemsInCsv();
        $ssp->setAllowedItemsPerPage([5, 10, 20, -1]);

        $ssp->setColumns([
            ['label'=>'ID',         'db'=>'id',            'formatter' => function ($value, $model) {
                return str_pad($value, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
            }],
            ['label'=>'Email',      'db'=>'email',         ],
            ['label'=>'Username',   'db'=>'uname',         ],
            ['label'=>'Created At', 'db'=>'created_at',    ],
            ['label'=>'Action',     'db'=>'id',            'formatter' => function ($value, $model) {
                $btns = [
                    '<button onclick="edit(\''.$value.'\');">Edit</button>',
                    '<button onclick="delete(\''.$value.'\');">Delete</button>',
                ];
                return implode($btns, " ");
            }],
            ['db'=>'email_verified_at'],
        ]);

        $ssp->setQuery(function ($selected_columns) {
            return \App\Models\User::select($selected_columns)
            ->where('status', 'active')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', '!=', 1);
                $query->orWhere('uname', '!=', 'superadmin');
            });
        });
        
        $this->ssp = $ssp;
    }
    
    public function page()
    {   
        return view('admin-panel.users-list', [
            'columns' => $this->ssp->getFrontEndColumns(),
            'is_search_enable' => $this->ssp->isSearchEnabled(),
            'allowed_items_per_page' => $this->ssp->getAllowedItemsPerPage(),
            'initial_items_per_page' => 10,
            'initial_order' => $this->ssp->getFrontEndInitialSorting('created_at', true),
        ]);
    }


    public function get()
    {
        return $this->ssp->response()->json();
    }
}
```

For more details, you can [visit the documentation page](https://info.souldoit.com/projects/laravel-datatable-ssp).